# setting selected value inside combobox using its name not index

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I'm rendering combobox like this

```
    $('#MyCombo').html('<option value=""></option>');
    $.each(mydata, function (i, v) {
       $('#MyCombo').append('<option value="' + v.PersonId+ '">' + v.PersonName + '</option>');
    });
```

how can I set selected value inside combobox if `v.PersonName == 'John'`

p.s. I know that I can set value using it's index

```
 $('#MyCombo').prop('selectedIndex', 2);
```

but in this case I don't know the index, I just know the name.

Comment: `$('option[value=John]').prop('selected')`

Comment: @user1765862 the below solution will help you

Comment: please mask solution as answer so that it can help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Simple answer

```
$('#MyCombo').html('<option value=""></option>');
    $.each(mydata, function (i, v) {
       if (v.PersonName== 'John')
          $('#MyCombo').append('<option selected value="' + v.PersonId+ '">' + v.PersonName + '</option>');
       else
          $('#MyCombo').append('<option value="' + v.PersonId+ '">' + v.PersonName + '</option>');
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
$('#MyCombo').html('<option value=""></option>');
$.each(mydata, function (i, v) {
    $('#MyCombo').append('<option value="' + v.PersonId + '" '+ 
                         (v.PersonName == 'John ')? 'selected ' : '' +'>' + 
                         v.PersonName + '</option>');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this as

```
   $('#MyCombo').html('<option value=""></option>');
    $.each(mydata, function (i, v) {
       $('#MyCombo').append('<option value="' + v.PersonId+ '">' + v.PersonName + '</option>');
    });
$('#MyCombo').value = "Jhon'sId";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [jQuery.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function. I like this more then writing the full html twice.

[Example on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1t9c5dxm/)

```
var options = [
    { value: 'foo',  label: 'Lorem' },
    { value: 'bar', label: 'Ipsum' },
    { value: 'juice', label: 'Orange' }
];

$.each(options, function() {
    var option = $('<option/>')
        .text(this.label)
        .val(this.value);

    if ( this.value == 'bar' ) {
        option.prop('selected', 'selected');
    }

    option.appendTo($('select'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#MyCombo option').filter(function () { 
    return $(this).html() == "John"; 
}).prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
$('#MyCombo').html('<option value=""></option>');
$.each(mydata, function (i, v) 
{
    if(v.PersonName == 'John')
    {
        $('#MyCombo').append('<option value="' + v.PersonId + '"selected>' + v.PersonName + '</option>');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#MyCombo').append('<option value="' + v.PersonId + '">' + v.PersonName + '</option>');
    }
};
```